# Unity3D Displaying a RenderTexture overlayed ontop of another Camera

Tags: image-processing, unity-game-engine, camera, rendering

So to be simple I have a RenderTexture of another camera, and I need to overlay it onto another camera either through:

a) A RenderTexture of that camera

or

b) directly to the cameras rendering

What I'm trying to do can also be seen in this representation:
[fig1 shows the main render, fig2 shows the desired overlay to be applied, fig3 shows them applied in a way of overlay, fig4 shows post processing of the now newly edited image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdPDS.png)
Where the first box is the main camera, and the second is what I want overlayed onto it as a RenderTexture in OnRenderObject() A.K.A when these two get rendered. Then in OnPostRender() these are combined where the overlay will be ontop. Then in OnRenderImage(), image effects can freely change the combined images together.

So as a list of what I need help with in explaining is that:

- I do not know how to either:

  - Access the cameras rendering directly
    or
  - Set a RenderTexture as a cameras rendering in OnPostRender()
- I also need help though explanation in correctly overlaying a RenderTexture onto either one of the above (This would be using the depth rendered to the RenderTexture as alpha) just as shown in fig3 of the image.

This is the method I've thought up in order to overlay a forward rendering onto deferred for image effects. If you have any other solutions or ideas, it'd be very well appreciated if you could post them as a comment.

Just to clarify I'm not asking for source code, just methods and or links to Unity3D's documentation of said methods that I'm asking about.

Thank you very much so in advance. :)

Comment: Hi Jayden -- to be clear.  In Unity (or any game engine) it's totally normal to use ***more than one camera*** at a time.  So, if you have say a room with a gun or something apparently near the front, that is sone with a separate camera and scene sitting "off to the side" and then you combine them.  I totally don't understand your use case but almost certainly you'll simply use "another camera or two" for the items "on top".

Comment: Yeah, that is completely true. However the thing is, is that the clear flag of 'depth only' doesn't work with Deferred Rendering, which is what I need for image effects; and so I cannot combine two renderings without removing the image effects needed.That's why instead of the conventional way, I'm trying to combine a Forward rendering with a primary Deferred rendering to then use image effects on as shown in the image.

Comment: to be honest I have absolutely no clue what you mean! :)  Sorry!  :) But to be sure, you are already are familiar with using many cameras, so ... good luck!  :-)

Comment: Haha, that's alright. Thank you to your comments either way :)

Comment: heh!  they may help a beginner